# safeSearch filter videos but it is not ip restriction. Is it a bug?

Tags: youtube-api

Whether i tried http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/t_vuWv0C8mbjQAe-5RKKrQ/uploads?v=2&start-index=1&max-results=50&prettyprint=True&safeSearch=none, http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/t_vuWv0C8mbjQAe-5RKKrQ/uploads?v=2&start-index=1&max-results=50&prettyprint=True&safeSearch=moderate, http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/t_vuWv0C8mbjQAe-5RKKrQ/uploads?v=2&start-index=1&max-results=50&prettyprint=True&safeSearch=strict

The result is filtered and only return 1 video.

However, if i remove **safeSearch** parameter ,  http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/t_vuWv0C8mbjQAe-5RKKrQ/uploads?v=2&start-index=1&max-results=50&prettyprint=True, i can get many videos.

I didn't think it's related to ip restriction, the feed didn't return **yt$state** and something like ""This video is not available in your region.". I can play all videos on the browser with the same ip. it is not related to restriction parameter, http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/t_vuWv0C8mbjQAe-5RKKrQ/uploads?v=2&start-index=1&max-results=50&prettyprint=True&restriction=127.0.0.1&safeSearch=none still return 1 video.

My question is, what restriction exactly cause safeSearch filter my result, if not ip restriction, what else? 18+ video?

[image: Only one video returned]

[image: More videos returned]

Answer (score 1):

You're getting back different results because your first set of queries all go against the search index, and your other query goes against the backend database. This is explained in more detail at http://apiblog.youtube.com/2012/03/keeping-things-fresh.html

Comment: thanks,

I need both restriction=IP and safeSearch=strict for ip restriction(even though it's not 100%,i know).

Example, http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/FoxNewsChannel/uploads?v=2&start-index=1&max-results=20&alt=json&prettyprint=True&restriction=MY return "This video is not available in your region". However if i add safeSearch parameter, http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/FoxNewsChannel/uploads?v=2&start-index=1&max-results=20&alt=json&prettyprint=True&restriction=MY&safeSearch=none would filter these videos. If searchSearch go against the search index, what is the solutions?